Optional argument has wrong value when used with action trigger
QGIS 3.36.2, Python 3.12.3
I've got a regular action that is part of a toolbar and that calls a function when pressed, which uses an optional argument with a default value:
class MyClass:
    def createToolbar(self):
        toolbar_old = iface.mainWindow().findChild(QToolBar,"mytoolbar")
        if toolbar_old: toolbar_old.deleteLater()
        
        toolbar = QToolBar("mytoolbar")
        toolbar.setObjectName("mytoolbar")
        action = QAction("Start",toolbar)
        action.triggered.connect(self.doSomething)
        toolbar.addAction(action)
        iface.addToolBar(toolbar)
    
    def doSomething(self,donextthing=True):
        print(donextthing)
        
mc = MyClass()

mc.doSomething() prints True and mc.doSomething(False) prints False, as expected.
The problem: When I click the "Start" button, then it prints False, even though the default value is True.
With a lambda (action.triggered.connect(lambda: self.doSomething())) it correctly prints True but I was told to avoid lambdas.
Why does this happen (is it a bug?)? How do I fix this, without making the argument non-optional?

It happens because the triggered signal passes the value of the QAction’s checked state to any connected slots. Your slot is receiving that value, which is false by default. Because the signal is passing a value, it overrides the default you have specified for the donextthing argument--i.e., it isn't ignoring the default, it's just passing a value.
A lambda is the simplest way to do what you are trying to do. Making the parameter mandatory will not change anything, as triggered is already passing a value.

Thanks! The docs even mention checked (no idea how I missed that). A lambda is probably the "cleaner" solution but I also added checked as the first optional parameter (def doSomething(self,checked=False,donextthing=True)) and two tests with that were successful, so that would be an alternative.
